# how to shift code up or down with the up and down arrow keys on vs code mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

On linux, i press alt + up or down to shift code up or down on vs code.

how do i do the same on mac?

Comment: Found by using this new magical tool called "a search engine" using the term `vscode macos keyboard shortcuts`; https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: That's not the same thing. There is a way to shift a line of code up or down. not scrolling the window

Comment: Your question was unclear. But the crib sheet I found on your behalf answer the "move line of code" question.

Comment: what is the commandID for the key combo on linux, search for the same commandID on the mac

Answer (score 0):

it's a command `Move Line Up/Down`.

1. open `show all command` with `shift+cmd+p`
2. type `Preferences: Open keyboard shortcuts`
3. search `move line`
4. look what keybinding you have (mine was `option + up/down`)